# Error launching Eclipse Application from Vogella Tutorial

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I try to convert multiple Eclipse plugins into a single RCP-Application as described in Vogellas Tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#plugin_creatinge4).
But when i launch the application i get the following error "java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found".

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2):

"No application id has been found" almost always means that you're missing some required plug-ins.  Go to the **Run Configurations** dialog, move over to the **Plug-ins** tab, and push the **Validate Plug-ins** button.  You'll be presented with a small dialog showing the names of plugins whose constraints aren't being satisfed, often because on the aforementioned **Plug-ins** tab, those plugins don't have their check boxes selected.

The **Add Required Plug-ins** button on the **Plug-ins** tab will often fix the problems for you.  If that doesn't work, take a closer look at the plugins that are listed and see if anything looks wonky; maybe a plugin that you know your application needs isn't on the list at all, because you forgot to add it to your workspace or your target platform?

If you still can't puzzle it out, search SO for `[eclipse-rcp] "no application id"` for more debugging ideas.